# Arduino, Convert minutes to hh mm sec

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Would you please help with this:

I have a long code in Arduino to control a water circulation system, However, I can calculate the remaining time to end the operation in minutes. For example, 3780.67 min. 
Would you please write a code to convert these minute to be displayed in Hours, Minutes, Seconds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
float minutes_total = 63.5; // example data

int hours = minutes_total / 60;
int minutes = minutes_total - (hours * 60);
int seconds = (minutes_total - (hours * 60) - minutes) * 60;
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino millis to Hours

If you want to get to hours when using Arduino millis as a Timer you need to do some more division:

```
 Minutes = ( millis()/1000 ) / 60;

 Hours = ( ( millis()/1000 ) / 60 ) / 60;
```

Arduino millis to Days

The full set of time values is here:

```
 Days = Hours/24;

 Hours = Minutes / 60;

 Minutes = Seconds / 60;

 Seconds = millis()/1000;
```

The variable days can only have a maximum value of 49.7 days (rollover of millis() ).
Note: Since Hours. Minutes and Seconds and Days can only have a maximum value below 255 you can use type uint8_t for each of the above quantities. uint8_t is the same as "unsigned char".
Here a function to enable clock display:

```
unsigned long Now = millis()/1000;
// we use modulo to split the parts
int Seconds = Now%60;
int Minutes = (Now/60)%60;
int Hours = (Now/3600)%24;
int Days = (Now/3600*24);
String time = Days + "-" + Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds ;
 Serial.println(time);
```

**EDIT** Special need to use float (?) as time input

```
float time = 723.5;
int Seconds = 60 * (time - (int)time + 0.00005); // rounding for extraction needed
// we use modulo to split the parts and int casting to extract integer part
int Minutes = (int)(time )%60; // we cast float to int
int Hours = ((int)time /60)%24;
int Days = ((int)time /60*24);
String timeDisplay = Days + "-" + Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds ;
 Serial.println(timeDisplay);
```

Comment: I have tried your code but I got wrong data.
The time in minutes already known from another operation. Let say float min = xxx.xx 
I am trying to convert it to dd hh mm sec

Comment: Where does the float come from ? Arduino uses unsigned long for time? Anyway I edit my code tosatisfy your (very special) need

Comment: the float comes from another calculation based on a flowrate data and total liter of liquid

Comment: Edited answer see a more ellegant solution